# Using Multiple Recursive functions in Python

Tags: python, recursion

I am computing sum of digits of a number recursively, until sum is less than 10. For example;

```
99999->45->9
```

Since final sum of digits is 9, then we stop. I am aware of following recursive approach which works fine, in my knowledge;

**First Approach**

```
def sumdigits(n):
    if n//10==0:
       return n
    q,r=divmod(n,10)
    return sumdigits(q+r)
```

But I am trying to write it using two recursive functions, in order to learn a different approach. Here is my second approach;

**Second Approach**

```
def digitalRoot(n):
    def sumdigits(n):
        if n==0:
            return 0
        q,r=divmod(n,10)
        return r+sumdigits(q)
    s=sumdigits(n)
    if s//10==0:
       return s
    q,r=divmod(s,10)
    return r+sumdigits(q)
```

As seen, I am trying to write a separate check whether sum of digit is less than 10. It is working for situations where the level of calculation is at most 2.
For example `n=99999` gives the sum as `99999->45->9`.

But if we have case like `n=27640`, the correct output she be 1, since `27640->19->10->1.` But my code is stopping at second level and giving answer as `10.` Can I get some help to modify my second code so as to fix the issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Third approach: `def digitalRoot(n): return n % 9`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an iterative solution already provided by Hans that does what you want, here is a recursive approach.

You are doing it right but like Hans pointed out "At no point have you encoded the logic that says "and do this till we get an answer less than 10."". Just added that condition to what your code already did.

```
def sum_digits(num):
    '''
    Returns the sum of individual digits in a number
    eg: 123 -> 1+2+3 -> 6
    '''
    if num<10:
        return num
    q,r=divmod(num,10)
    return r+sum_digits(q)

def sum_till_single_digit(num):
    '''
    Does `sum_digits` recursively till the sum is a single digit
    eg: 99 -> 9+9 -> 18 -> 1+8 -> 9
    '''
    if num<10:
        return num
    return sum_till_single_digit(sum_digits(num))

print(sum_till_single_digit(27640)) # 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers, colleagues. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you're only ever computing at most two levels. At no point have you encoded the logic that says "and do this till we get an answer less than 10." So...let's do that.

```
def sum_digits(n):
  t = 0
  while n:
    n, r = divmod(n, 10)
    t += r
  return t

def digital_root(n):
  while n >= 10:
    n = sum_digits(n)
  return n
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sum() and map() to obtain the sum of digits from the string version of the number.

Then the recursion simply needs to check if the result is less than 10:

```
def numerologic(n):
    s = sum(map(int,str(n)))
    return s if s<10 else numerologic(s)
```

or on a single line:

```
def numerologic(n): return n if n<10 else numerologic(sum(map(int,str(n))))
```